# Legacy Data File to Graph

Tags: c#, dataset, datasource, raw-data

My program should:

1. Load a data table from a legacy raw data file.
2. Provide an interface to display, filter, graph, etc.

My approach is to create an in-memory database as a DataSource for binding the filter controls, results grid, graphs, etc.

**Question:**
What is the simplest way to define and populate this in-memory database?

**Edit:**
I only have a minimal knowledge of LINQ.  In the past, I'd always been able to just drag a database table or query into the form or webpage.  Visual Studio would create the DataSet, DataTable, DataSource, etc objects for me.

... where do I define this structure (an XML file, in-code, wizard, drag and drop)?  what data objects do I need?  etc

Comment: What kind of size is the input file? How many rows?

Comment: About 100k rows by 20 columns

Comment: So, just create a class with the properties by which you need to search/filter/sort and another class that creates instances of those classes populated with data read from your file. There are plenty of LINQ extension methods to help you with advanced searching/sorting and reprojecting the objects. Am I missing something?

Comment: ... my minimal knowledge of LINQ.  See main post edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create classes containing the necessary properties and then simply parse the file and populate those classes in-memory. Here you go, you've got an in-memory database.

> I only have a minimal knowledge of LINQ

Here's a good start for you: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

> where do I define this structure (an XML file, in-code, wizard, drag and drop)?

If you want to store the data in-memory define strongly typed C# classes that match your data.

> what data objects do I need?

That would entirely depend on what information you have in your file and you want to handle.

Comment: so... rather than defining a `DataSource` (for binding the values of filter controls, grid, graphs, etc), you recommend just updating those values with my own methods?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You could define models that represent your data and then simply bind the UI object DataSources to those models.

Comment: You answered my question (manually set values instead of DataBind).  I'll post another question about how to implement the DataBind approach.  Thanks!